# Debugging into native C++ code of Android platform/framework libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, java-native-interface

I have an Android app that uses classes from the Android framework/platform, for example [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack). I'd like to find out more about how those classes work internally by stepping into the code of those classes. I've managed to set up the Android Studio debugger to step into the Java part, [AudioTrack.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioTrack.java;l=88). I also want to step into the C++ part, [AudioTrack.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/av/media/libaudioclient/AudioTrack.cpp), that is called from the Java part via JNI.

How can I set up Android Studio to step into the C++ part of AudioTrack, from the Java part? Where can I get the sources and debug symbols for AudioTrack from, and how to tell Android Studio about them?

Just to be clear: My app doesn't contain native code on its own, I want to debug into the native code of the Android platform itself.

**Some more background and info:**

I use Android Studio 4.2.2, running my app in the emulator `Pixel_3a_API_30_x86`. My app uses 30 for the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, and in the SDK Manager I have "Source for Android 30" installed. That means stepping into Java platform code like `AudioTrack.java` works fine. However, in `~/Library/Android/sdk/sources/`, I can only find `AudioTrack.java`, not `AudioTrack.cpp`, and no debug symbols for `libandroid_runtime.so` (which is the library that contains the native code for `AudioTrack`).

I've set the debugger type of the run configuration of my app in Android Studio to "Dual (Java + Native)".

When encountering a call to a native method via JNI, the debugger in Android Studio just steps over the function, even when using "Force Step Into". Example of such a native method call:
[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

I can set breakpoints in native code with LLDB commands, like this:

```
(lldb) br set --name android_media_AudioTrack_start
Breakpoint 4: where = libandroid_runtime.so`android_media_AudioTrack_start(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*), address = 0xe5a7eb00
```

However, when the debugger stops at that breakpoint, Android Studio shows no source code and no variables due to source code and debug symbols not being available:
[image: Android Studio debugger screenshot]

Comment: Every device will have its own build of the Android runtime libraries, which means you need to get these debug symbols from your device vendor. I am not aware of any such offerings currently.

Comment: @Botje So even for standard emulator images from Google, debug symbols are not available?